# java generic related to type inference

Tags: java

I'm a java newbie, and I have some codes like below.

```
public interface TestJava<T extends MyClass, U> {
    public U func(T t);
}
```

The problem is that *U* is totally dependant on *T* so that if *T* is determined, *U* is also determined (declaring *U* is unnecessary!). As an example, if *T* is *String*, then *U* must be *Integer* and cannot be others. In *C++*, *U* can be easily removed using the keyword *typedef* like below if *T* is a user-defined class.

```
class UserDefinedClass {
public:
    typedef int ReturnType;
};

template<class T> class TestCpp {
    T::ReturnType func(T t);
};
```

However, java doen't have such keyword (as far as I know), so I have no idea how to achieve this.
Note that *T* in the java code is a user-defined object, not *String*, *Integer* or others.
Don't get confused with the example :)

Comment: There is no general way to achieve such a constraint. I might suggest defining `interface TestJavaStringToInteger extends TestJava<String, Integer>` (obv, with a better name...), which has a method `Integer func(String t)`; however, there is nothing to stop you having another interface which `extends TestJava<String, Frobnitz>`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is hide the eyesore by extending the interface and then from then on just call the extended interface. The point here is that you don't have to pass in the second type if you are SURE it will always be (eg: Integer*) the same.

```
public class MyClass{
  boolean truth;  
}

public interface Lame{       
}

public interface TestJava<T extends MyClass, U> {
    public U func(T t);
}

public interface TestJavaMore<T extends MyClass> extends Lame{
    public void funky();
}

public interface TestJavaEvenMore<T extends MyClass> extends TestJava<T, Integer> {

}
```

Another solution which I think I would recommend if you have more than one combination of types for T and U is to use a factory to create a concrete instance with the types you want. This is a common pattern you can research, but in this case, it's something like:

```
public class TestJavaImpl<T extends MyClass, U> implements TestJava{
        @Override
        public Object func(MyClass t) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        }
    }

    public TestJava TestJavaFactory(){
        TestJava testJava = null;
        if (true == true){
            testJava = new TestJavaImpl<MyClass, Integer>();
        } else {
            testJava = new TestJavaImpl<MyClass, Float>();
        }
        return testJava;
    }
```

*Tip:Remember too w/ java and templates you have to use "I"nteger not "i"nteger